# Dynamic Generic Typing in Java

Tags: java, generics

If I have a class using generic type such as

```
public class Record<T> {
    private T value;

    public Record(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

it is pretty straight forward to type everything during design time, if I know all types that are used such as it is the case in this example:

```
// I type explicitly
String myStr = "A";
Integer myInt = 1;
ArrayList myList = new ArrayList();

Record rec1 = new Record<String>(myStr);
Record rec2 = new Record<Integer>(myInt);
Record rec3 = new Record<ArrayList>(myList);
```

What happens if I get a list of objects from "somewhere" where I don't know the type? How do I assign the type:

```
// now let's assume that my values come from a list where I only know during runtime what type they have

ArrayList<Object> myObjectList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    myObjectList.add(myStr);
    myObjectList.add(myInt);
    myObjectList.add(myList);

    Object object = myObjectList.get(0);

    // this fails - how do I do that?
    new Record<object.getClass()>(object);
```

Comment: Generics is for compile time strong typing. It's pretty much useless if you have no idea about the type you are trying to infer. You should design it in such a way that there is at least a known interface or a base class that you could use. You could do `new Record<Object>(object)` I guess.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Java generics are not C++ Templates.

Java generics are a compile time feature, not a run time feature.

Here is a link to the [Java generics Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

**This can never work with Java:**

```
new Record<object.getClass()>(object);
```

You must either use polymorphism (say, each object implements a known interface) or RTTI (instanceof or Class.isAssignableFrom()).

You might do this:

```
     class Record
     {
       public Record(String blah) { ... }
       public Record(Integer blah) { ... }
       ... other constructors.
     }
```

or you might use the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. Your wording seems to imply, that C++ Templates are a runtime feature, but they aren't. They are even more compile time then the Java Generics.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that ultimately you have to take into account all types that you will create. If you are limiting to a few types, this is OK. What if you are using a lot of types, or if you want to put in "any" type? I would consider this a bad solution for this reason. There may, ultimately, be no good solution to this problem due to this limitation in Generics...

Comment: The problem you describe is a symptom of a terrible design and does not represent a limitation in Generics, it represents a problem that is outside of the scope of Generics.  If you need to play the game of "I R Guud four al typs", use a scripting language.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning overloading; I'm in a Java job now after working in Python and I forget those exist.

Answer (score 5):

### Creating instances from Generic Types at Runtime

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but at a first glance it looks like the simplest solution is the best solution.

It could be solved with using a scripting environment ( Groovy, JavaScript, JRuby, Jython ) that could dynamically evaluate and execute arbitrary code to create the objects, but that got extremely convoluted and overly complex, just to create an object.

But unfortunately I think it has a very pedestrian solution.

As long as there is a predefined set of supported types, you can use a `Factory` pattern. Here I just leverage the `Provider<>T` interface from the `javax.inject`/`com.google.inject` package.

#### [Q26289147_ProviderPattern.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q26289147_ProviderPattern.java)

```
public class Q26289147_ProviderPattern
{
    private static final List<String> CLASS_NAMES = ImmutableList.of("String", "Integer", "Boolean");
    private static final Map<String, Provider<StrawManParameterizedClass>> PROVIDERS;

    static
    {
        final ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Provider<StrawManParameterizedClass>> imb = ImmutableMap.builder();
        for (final String cn : CLASS_NAMES)
        {
            switch (cn)
            {
                case "String":
                    imb.put(cn, new Provider<StrawManParameterizedClass>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public StrawManParameterizedClass<String> get() { return new StrawManParameterizedClass<String>() {}; }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Integer":
                    imb.put(cn, new Provider<StrawManParameterizedClass>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public StrawManParameterizedClass<Integer> get() { return new StrawManParameterizedClass<Integer>() {}; }
                    });
                    break;
                case "Boolean":
                    imb.put(cn, new Provider<StrawManParameterizedClass>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public StrawManParameterizedClass<Integer> get() { return new StrawManParameterizedClass<Integer>() {}; }
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("%s is not a supported type %s", cn, Joiner.on(",").join(CLASS_NAMES)));
            }
        }
        PROVIDERS = imb.build();
    }

    static <T> void read(@Nonnull final StrawManParameterizedClass<T> smpc) { System.out.println(smpc.type.toString()); }

    static abstract class StrawManParameterizedClass<T>
    {
        final TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};

        @Override
        public String toString() { return type.getRawType().getCanonicalName(); }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        for (final String cn : CLASS_NAMES)
        {
            read(PROVIDERS.get(cn).get());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Disclaimer:

> This is just a proof of concept example, I would never use a `switch`
>   statement like that in production code I would use a `Strategy
>   Pattern` or `Chain of Responsibility` Pattern to encapsulate the logic
>   of what type to create based on the `ClassName` key.

#### This initially looked like a generics problem, it isn't, it is a creation problem.

That said, you don't need to pass around instances of `Class<?>` you can get `Generic Type` information off of Parameterized classes at runtime with `TypeToken` from Guava.

You can even create instances of any generic type at runtime with `TypeToken` from the Guava library.

The main problem is this syntax isn't supported: `Geography<myClass.newInstance()> geo;` and I can't think of anyway to fake it other than the `Provider` implementation above.

> Here is a straw man example of how to use `TypeToken` so that your
>   parameterized classes will always know their types!

#### [Q26289147.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q26289147.java)

```
import com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken;

public class Q26289147
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException
    {
        final StrawManParameterizedClass<String> smpc = new StrawManParameterizedClass<String>() {};
        final String string = (String) smpc.type.getRawType().newInstance();
        System.out.format("string = \"%s\"",string);
    }

    static abstract class StrawManParameterizedClass<T>
    {
        final TypeToken<T> type = new TypeToken<T>(getClass()) {};
    }
}
```

#### Notes:

1. Works great for classes that have a default no arg constructor.
2. Works better than using straight reflection if there are no default no arg constructors.
3. Should play well with Guice allowing you to use the `.getRawType()` generated `Class<T>` to pass to `getInstance()` of an Injector. *have not tried this yet, I just thought of it!*
4. You can use `Class<T>.cast()` to do casting that doesn't need `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the type, you cannot enforce compile time checks with generics.

Just for the sake of using it you could say

```
new Record<Object>(object);
```