# Need to pass a Generic Class Type parameter, based on qualified Class name string

Tags: java, generics

Only at run-time am I passed the fully qualified Class name (ie "com.firm.me.MyClass")

I need to instantiate a Generic class defined as, say :

```
Class A <T>
{
}
```

Where "T" is the type associated with the passed in fully qualified class name.

I have the following :

```
Class <?> clazz = Class.forName ("com.firm.me.MyClass");
```

I want (logically speaking) to have something like ..

```
A <clazz> myInstance = new A <clazz>;
```

The use of "clazz" in the positions above gives rise to following errors :

"clazz cannot be resolved to a type".

How can I do what I want (logically) to do.

Many thanks.

Comment: Due to type erasure `A<clazz> myInstance` would resolve to `A myInstance` anyways, so even if you got this working, you'd have no benefit from that. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a serialized persisted data store. There could be several stores and within each store all objects are of the same type.The class example I gave above "class A <T>" instantiates my persister/retriever class. What I want to do is to have the User enter the class name of the type of data persisted in their data store so I can then have a generic command-line based app which can then be used to retrieve their data. I wanted to instantiate the persister/retriever instance based on the fully qualified class name they enter from the command-line

Comment: @user1151685 you should declare a member variable in your class A which is initialized through the constructor.Let me know if the below solution solves your problem

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do such things in Java. Read about type [erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Besides the issue of type erasure -- which makes this impossible in any event -- you simply can't guarantee that `T` has an exposed, no-argument constructor!

The traditional workaround is to pass around factory objects that provide methods that can be used to obtain `T` objects. A simplistic example would be

```
interface Factory<T> {
  T create();
}
```

and then your class can get a `Factory<T>` and call `create()` on it to get more `T's`. More sophisticated examples might require additional arguments to a `create()` method, for example, or overloads.

Answer (score 0):

You should change to `Class A` to something like this:-

```
class A<T> {

    Class<T> clazz;

    public A(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<com.firm.me.MyClass> clazz = (Class<MyClass>) Class
                .forName("com.firm.me.MyClass");
        A<MyClass> myInstance = new A<MyClass>(clazz);
    }
}
```

Just create a constructor which takes a Class object.In this way ,not only are you getting the correct Class Object at runtime,you can use generics to treat your parameterized object the way you want

Answer (score 0):

In Java, generic types must be resolved on compile time. In fact, they are almost unaccesible at run time due to the famous *type-erasure* (check this: [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)).

Check this question about the same problem: [Dynamic Generic Typing in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342035/dynamic-generic-typing-in-java)

You should stick to the old non-typed `A` or to `A<Object>`, where you might include some runtime checks like
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29

Answer (score 0):

Generics are only used at compile-time for compile-time type checking. Therefore, if a type parameter is not known at compile time, it serves no purpose.