# How to pass argument to Generic type class in java

Tags: java, class, generics

I have class similar as given below

```
public class MyClass<K,V>{

 public MyClass(Properties prop){
  Map<K,V> myMap = new HashMap<K,V>();
 }

}
```

I need to invoke this class by passing `String` as `K` and `V` as `MyAnotherClass` , but the `MyAnotherClass` will be taken as an user input through file, how to create the `MyAnotherClass` from a given name from file, and pass the same to 
 `MyClass<String,MyAnotherClass> = new MyClass<String,MyAnotherClass>()` . what is the best way to achieve the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm *lost*.  What you're doing here will already let you create an instance of `MyClass<String, MyAnotherClass>`.

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is the problem and what are you stuck on?

Comment: i think she is talking about create a class from a String resolving the name

Comment: I want to create an instance similar to `MyClass<String,MyAnotherClass> = new MyClass<String,MyAnotherClass>()` , but the argument may be identified at the run time. Instead of `MyAnotherClass` it will be taken from String as mentioned by @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342035/dynamic-generic-typing-in-java

Comment: I have scenario ,where the class (full qualified path) will be passed as a string , Using that value , how i can create the `MyClass` instance

Comment: If you have full qualified path you can just use reflection to create an instance of your customclass. Maybe you can just create a wrapper class that take the string and reate an instance of the class indicated by it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java erases the types on compilation, so you need to have the user pass in the type (by passing in the `Class` object of the type) at runtime.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyClass<V extends Class<V>> {

    public MyClass(Properties prop, V type){
        Map<String,V> myMap = new HashMap<String,V>();
    }

}
```

will give you what you need.  It will be called like

```
new MyClass(properties, Customer.class);
```

Comment: Thanks , this approach fixed the issue.

Comment: @deva Glad it helped.  It was a problem I first encountered a long time ago (when Generics was just pre-release).  So, I'm glad I could share the answer I found.